# MYSQL INSERT VARIABLES / UPDATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, variables, view, insert

I fairly new to MYSQL. I have 3 tables

Table.... accounts
ROWS....  id : rp_total

Table... research
ROWS.... research_uid : cost

Table... completed_research
ROWS.... id : research_uid

I'm trying to run a script automatically that will look for id's that don't have all completed research and will insert a new row into the completed_research table with their ID and the completed research_uid if the rp_total amount is greater than the research_uid cost

This is hard to explain. Hopefully this makes sense. I'm trying to avoid looping through id's because there a potential for thousands to be updated at once. I'm guessing this is going to required a view or temporary table of some sort but I've been fighting with this for 2 solid days now.

Comment: Try to go easy on ALL CAPS, especially in the title. It's also important to explain the problem in more specific terms in the title so you can get the attention you need.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a SQL JOIN operation with the right WHERE clause. It would help if you showed the schema in a form that could be used to create a solution, like as in the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or as `CREATE TABLE x (...)`.

Comment: Pls follow the guidance in this meat post to improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you want, but must be close:

```
INSERT 
INTO
    completed_research(a_id, research_uid)
SELECT
    a.id,
    r.research_uid
FROM
    accounts a,
    research r
WHERE
    (
        a.INCOMPLETED_FIELD IS NULL AND a.id > r.research_uid
    );
```

"a.INCOMPLETED_FIELD" is your incomplete column in the `accounts` table, I not sure what are suppose to be, but I imagine that it could help you.

*Note that INSERT to "a_id" and not "ID" column, for good practices.